# Xsl: how to find out if a node or his descendant contain text

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

i'm having some difficulties to find out if a node or contains text.

Consider the followinw examples of xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<doc xml:lang="it">
    <articolo>
        <titolazione id="U20690661166yt" contentType="headline">
            <occhiello class="occhiello">
                <p>
                    <span class="parolachiave">L’ALTRO COLPO PER L’ATTACCO</span>
                </p>
            </occhiello>
            <titolo class="titolo">
                <p>Il gran giorno</p>
                <p>di Llorente:</p>
                <p>arriva a Torino </p>
                <p>e fa le visite</p>
            </titolo>
            <sommario class="catenaccio">
                <?EM-dummyText [sommario]?>
            </sommario>
        </titolazione>
    </articolo>
```

As you can see i have 3 nodes under "Titolazione": occhiello, titolo and sommario. I need to create a tempate that is able to understand if inside these 3 nodes there is text or not (at any level) and according to that add also the class "no-text", so i can style it differently.

Here is an example made for occhiello:

```
<xsl:template name="occhiello">
        <xsl:if test="/doc/articolo/titolazione/occhiello">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="string-length(normalize-space(/doc/articolo/titolazione/occhiello/*/text())) = 0">
                    <h6 class="overhead no-text">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="/doc/articolo/titolazione/occhiello/*" />
                    </h6>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <h6 class="overhead">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="/doc/articolo/titolazione/occhiello/*" />
                    </h6>
                </xsl:otherwise>

            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
```

Templates for "titolo" and "sommario" are the same, just the xpath is changing.
Now i noticed that this template get close to what i need but still mistaking some times. If you look at the example is recognizing that "titolo" has text, is recognizing that "sommario" has no text but for some reason is making a mistake with "titolazione". It's adding the "no-text" class even if there is text. I think maybe cause is not contained in the

tag but in a nested tag (i could have even more nested levels).

Any idea how to correct it?

Thanks All.

Comment: Could you show us some more of your XSLT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One useful way of checking for text at any subsequent level is to use `value-of`, as that, if run on a node that contains sub-nodes, will return you a concatenation of the text of those nodes.

XML

```
<foo>
    <bar>cat</bar>
    <bar2>fish</bar2>
</foo>
```

XSL

```
<xsl:value-of select='foo' />
```

== "catfish"

Not being certain of the output you're trying to achieve, I came up with this (**working demo at [this XMLPlayground](http://www.xmlplayground.com/MDI2Mw)**):

```
<xsl:template match="doc/articolo">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match='titolazione | occhiello | titolo | sommario'>
    <xsl:variable name='text'><xsl:value-of select='normalize-space(.)' /></xsl:variable>
    <h6>
        <xsl:if test='not(string-length($text))'><xsl:attribute name='class'>no-text</xsl:attribute></xsl:if>
        <xsl:value-of select='name()' /> (has <xsl:if test='not(string-length($text))'>no </xsl:if> text)
    </h6>
    <xsl:if test='name() = "titolazione"'><xsl:apply-templates /></xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: "use `value-of`, as that, if run on multiple nodes, will concatenate the text into a single string" - not true, in XSLT 1.0 if you do `<xsl:value-of select="something that matches multiple nodes"/>` then what you get back is the string value of the _first_ of those nodes in document order.  But in your example you're not taking the `value-of` multiple nodes, you're taking the `value-of` a single element node (the `foo`), which by definition is the concatenation of all that element's descendant text nodes (newline+spaces, cat, newline+spaces, fish, and newline).

Comment: In XSLT 2.0 it's different, in that case `value-of` _does_ concatenate the values of multiple nodes (separated by a space) rather than just taking the first one.

Comment: @Ian - yes, you're right. I know what I meant (as do you, I think) but I explained it poorly. I meant if you run it on a node that has multiple nodes as children or descendants underneath it.

Comment: i'm using xsl 1.0 is this only 2,0 solution i could not understand

Comment: No, my solution is XSLT 1.0.

Comment: Thanks, seems working, i changed it a little bit but the value-of tip seems doing is job :)

Answer (score 2):

How about the following:

```
<xsl:template match="occhiello | titolo | sommario">
  <h6 class="overhead {substring('no-text', 1, 7 * not(normalize-space()))}">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
  </h6>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Sorry i cannot understand what it does, can you explain it to me please

Comment: @user280560 Could you show us your full XSLT? I need that in order to show you where this would fit into it.